# Waiting for a timeout until refreshing Guava Loading Cache

Tags: java, guava, throttling

I have some methods that will refresh a guava loading cache. Those methods are being called throughout the application. From within my service, I want to be able to throttle those refreshes.

I want to catch all requests for refreshes and if nothing came in after let's say 1 second, I want to refresh the cache.

I was thinking about using the Guava Rate Limiter, but this doesn't really help me. Is there anything specific from guava or do I need to do it on my own?
Thanks